# Calculated member based on a particular level in a hierarchy in SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a particular dimension which has a multi level hierarchy because of the self join that i have in the dimension table.

In a particular level of hierarchy, I have values like Revenues and Expenses. I have a to frame a calculated member to get the Total Revenues and Expenses

I tried this and i am getting `NULL` while browsing the cube

```
AGGREGATE({[Account Hierarchy].[Account Hierarchy].Properties( "Account Name" )="Revenues"},[Measures].[Budget]))
```

Please let me know what i am missing here.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should be using a Member reference not accessing the Properties.

I would use the BIDS Cube / Calculations / Metadata pane to find that Member and drag it into the calculation to get the correct syntax.